# Why does Concurrent Dictionary not have a visible Add() Method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency

I was just wondering how it was possible that ConcurrentDictionary does not have an Add method which is visible in the Visual Studio IDE. I only seem to get the TryX Methods e.g TryAdd, TryUpdate etc.

I can see that the `ConcurrentDictionary` implements `IDictionary` and if I cast it to `IDictionary` I get the Add Method back.

I have looked at the class through iLSpy and I can see the Add Method is fully implemented and does actually call the Concurrent `TryAdd` Method under the hood.

I was expecting to see some sort of Attribute on the Add method to surpress it but I am not seeing anything.

Has this been baked into the IDE by Microsoft to hide the Add method by default ??

If someone could shed some light on this it would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because of **explicit interface implementation**. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @AlexG I imagine it's simply because you *almost* certainly shouldn't be using `Add`, it's hard to use correctly if other threads may be modifying the same dictionary at the same time.

Comment: It's just an artifact of explicit implmentation that I never really thought about. You can implement from 2 interfaces that both support the same method. This has to be hidden on the concrete class as otherwise .Net would not know which version should be called. I don't think there is a conflicting interface on ConcurrentDictionary I think (As you said) it has been done just to make you use the concurrent methods and think a bit more about how you should use it.

Comment: Actually I'm wondering why MS at all derives ConcurrentDictionary from IDictionary! The ConcurrentDictionary should encourage you to use TryAdd() instead of a ContainsKey()/Add() pair since the latter is not safe in concurrent contexts. This is done by hiding those methods. But as soon as one takes an IDictionary and you pass your ConcurrentDictionary any concurrency-safety is gone! So: why is doing MS this?

Comment: link in answer is no longer working (big surprise msdn!) Alternative answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: @mmmmmmmm: well, the better question is why someone should cast a ConcurrentDictionary to IDictionary if he wants to use it as a ConcurrentDictionary(thread safe dictionary).

Comment: @mmmmmmmm: no. Add is just a wrapper to TryAdd, which throws an exception if key already exists. so thread-safety is not gone.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: This could happen easily if a method accepts an IDictionary as parameter. And you call it with the ConcurrentDicrionary

Comment: @VivekMVK: Okay...but it can't prevent the use of the ContainsKey()/Add() pattern which maybe called on the IDictionary without worrying.

Answer (score 9):

They are discouraging the use of the `Add` method because the method throws an exception if the key is already present in the dictionary. For most dictionaries, the developer can write code in a way to guarantee that the exception will not be thrown under any normal scenario. However, to perform this operation (`Contains` followed by `Add`) with a *concurrent* dictionary, you would need to use exclusive locks in methods accessing the dictionary, which defeats the entire purpose of a concurrent dictionary.

`TryAdd` combines the `Contains` and `Add` checks without requiring you to lock the dictionary, and allows you to once again write code that won't throw an exception in normal scenarios.